# Session.Save() does not save with NHibernate.JetDriver

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using *NHibernate.JetDriver* to persist my entities in an *Microsoft Access* database.
I have a simple table named Employee with 3 columns:

- Id (auto generated number)
- FirstName (text)
- LastName (text)

Here is the corresponding entity:

```
class Employee
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And the Mapping (using *Fluent NHibernate*):

```
class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
    }
}
```

Then I have the following code wich configure the SessionFactory (using *Fluent NHibernate*), create a new *Employee* and save it to the database:

```
var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(JetDriverConfiguration.Standard
        .ConnectionString(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
            Data Source=.\Company.accdb")
        .ShowSql)
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
        .AddFromAssemblyOf<EmployeeMap>())
    .BuildSessionFactory();

var employee = new Employee
{
    FirstName = "Laurent",
    LastName = "De Cant"
};

using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var id = session.Save(employee);
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

My problem is the following: the employee does not seem to be persisted in the database.
I have no exception and the id returned by *Save* is correct. Everything seems to be alright except that when I check the data in the table, There is no employee...

Using ShowSql option, here is the generated SQL:

```
NHibernate: INSERT INTO `Employee` (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?, ?);
@p0 = 'Laurent' [Type: String (7)], @p1 = 'De Cant' [Type: String (7)]
NHibernate: select @@identity
```

Here is what NHibernate profiler gives me:

```
-- statement #1
begin transaction with isolation level: Unspecified

-- statement #2
INSERT INTO `Employee`
            (FirstName,
             LastName)
VALUES      (?,
             ?)

-- statement #3
select @@identity

-- statement #4
commit transaction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking at the wrong database. During the build process the database file is copied to the output folder. If you check the database in the output folder the Employee record will be present.

Comment: You are true. I don't believe I was missing such a basic point... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you download a trial of [NHProf](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof%20NHProf%20is%20database%20independent) you should see if a session is being opened, the transaction being started, the SQL that is being sent and whether the session is throwing an error or not. If it is throwing an error it may be getting swallowed somewhere. NHProf is database independent so it will work with the Jet drivers.

Mind you you are getting the `auto number` back so I am not sure but I am sure NHProf will help you see what is going on. I wonder if it is because your `birthdate` column is a string and your property on the entity is a `dateTime` type?

Usually if no row is being persisted then this indicates that the entity `Employee` is not being added to the session factory, however in your case it clearly shows that it is...  Please note that NHibernate does not throw exceptions if you try to persist an unmapped entity.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, i will install the profiling tool and see what's happening.

There was effectively a mistake with the Birthdate property. To avoid confusion, I have deleted the property and edited the question accordingly.

Also, I added generated SQL.

Comment: I have edited the original post to add statements details from NHibernate Profiler.

Comment: What happens if you run that SQL straight in access? The back ticks look a little suspicious to me

Comment: It gives me the following error 'Characters found at end of sql statement. However, the request works well when I bypass parameters by putting raw values into _VALUES_ clause. Actually, _Access_ doesn't seem to support multi statements queries. Is there a way to make NHibernate generate single statement queries?